# removing similar rows from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

Brand new to data science and wanted to take up a simple project (using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.7). Basically I want to use NLP to find the most common phrases in the top 50 American TV shows. However, I've run into a snag. The dataset I have stores a show's season as an individual entry. So for example, I have something that looks like this:

- South Park Season 14
- Family Guy Season 3
- South Park Season 10
- South Park Season 11
- South Park Season 13
- Family Guy Season 1
- The Big Bang Theory Season 8

I'm interested in the top 50 *unique* shows. Is there a way to filter or remove similar entries in a Pandas DataFrame? Something that would keep the first entry, but remove all others? (I plan on collecting the transcripts of every episode from each show, so the first instance of the TV show doesn't matter so long as the similar entries are removed to make room for other unique entries).

I'm trying to figure out something that would return this (based on the example above):

- South Park Season 14
- Family Guy Season 3
- The Big Bang Theory Season 8

Unfortunately, I'm a total newbie and don't know where to start, be it regular expressions, string slicing, etc.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please add whatever little you have tried in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a standard naming convention, so you can use regular expressions here to drop duplicates based on the text that comes before a particular season.

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'show': {0: 'South Park Season 14',
  1: 'Family Guy Season 3',
  2: 'South Park Season 10',
  3: 'South Park Season 11',
  4: 'South Park Season 13',
  5: 'Family Guy Season 1',
  6: 'The Big Bang Theory Season 8'}})
```

---

#### `str.extract` + `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.loc[
  df.show.str.extract(r'(.*)\s?Season').drop_duplicates().index
]
```

```
                           show
0          South Park Season 14
1           Family Guy Season 3
6  The Big Bang Theory Season 8
```

If you merely wanted the show name, and not the specific season, it's even simpler:

```
 df.show.str.extract(r'(.*)\s?Season').drop_duplicates()
```

```
                     0
0           South Park
1           Family Guy
6  The Big Bang Theory
```

Comment: This was a pretty basic example, and there are different variations after the show's title, but this is a great place to start. For the different variations, I assume I can use conditionals and [^ ] ?Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates your problem in your question? Fuzzy string matching is another option here.

Comment: Fuzzy string matching looks like it may help better.

So aside from the above titles, I also have instances like "Grey's Anatomy: The Fourth Season" and messy data like "Scorpion&#039;"